# create a query delete in gorm

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Good morning, I need to perform the following query of the SQL server in Grails Hibernate (Gorm).
I do not understand how to perform the top of the query

```
("delete CORE_NOTIFICATIONS where id in (select top 1000 ID form CORE_EVENT where date <10)")
```

In gorm I did it like that but it gives error

```
query = "delete CoreNotifications CN where CN.event_id in (select top? ID from CoreEvent CE where CE.date <?)"
res = CoreNotifications.executeUpdate (query, params)
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: The error in exception is:

unexpected token: top
unexpected token: ID

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you are likely to use GORM to delete records interest. Below is the snippet of code what I used to do with my project. As you mentioned in the comment below, parallelism is recommended because the table contains three million records.

```
Date specifiedDate = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", "2010-04-03 1:23:45") // pass your date here by extrating from params
def result = CoreEvent.where { date < specifiedDate }
List<Integer> iDs = result.list(sort: "date").collect { it.id }

GparsPool.withPool {

   iDs.eachParallel {
      // we need to wrap inside a single transaction for parallelism
      CoreNotifications.withTransaction {
         CoreNotifications.where { id == it }.deleteAll()
      }
   }
}
```

I hope this code would help you resolve your problem expectedly.

Comment: Is that I need to delegate that task to the database engine, since that query can bring 3000000 records

Comment: In that situation, I think your need might be more relevant to how to perform heavy job rather interact with GORM. In Groovy, we can benefit [GPars Framework] (http://gpars.org/1.0.0/guide/guide/index.html) which provides advanced tools to parallel jobs.

Comment: @wagego: see the updated code I have changed with adding parallelism

Comment: But are not you doing a memory load on the CoreEvent?
That's why I need the database engine to do the process.

Or I'm not understanding?

Comment: @wagego: If you doubt the procedure of getting the right records in CoreEvent table due to memory, you can process the work in batch mode. We are applying batch mode when exporting metadata of thousands records to XML file.
The second and third statements aim to get the list of core events that get involved in CoreNotifications. If these tables have millions records, the better way is to paginate and apply batch processing.

Comment: Tung

finally they accepted me to do it by means of stored procedure.
So the work was easier to perform.

From now on I thank you for the help you gave me